# Laravel returning blank query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm having problem with this. I'm accessing page using i.e http://example.com/?page=release&id=2

```
$page = request('page');
$id_rilisan = request('id');

...

if($page == "release") {

    $post = Rilisan::where('id_rilisan', '=', $id_rilisan)->first();

    if($post == null) {
        return view('errors.404');
    }

    return view('html.post')->with('post', $post);
}
```

and the data viewed in the post.blade.php is blank. It does showing the page but the supposed data is blank.

```
<div>{{ $post['sinopsisPendek'] }} .</div>
```

and App/Rilisan.php

```
class Rilisan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'rilisan';
    protected $primaryKey = "id_rilisan"; 
    protected $guarded = array('id_rilisan');
    public $timestamps  = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code is not a real checking for `null`:

```
if($post = null)
{
  return view('errors.404');
}
```

Note that `=` is assignment. For checking use `==` or `===`. See [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for differences.

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't notice that one

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `<div>{{ $post->sinopsisPendek }} .</div>` ?

Comment: I'm getting error `Trying to get property of non-object'

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo here: `if($post = null)` should be `if($post == null)`, that's why your data are blank.

Answer (score 0):

First you can make the query shorter.

$post = Rilisan::where('id_rilisan', '=', $id_rilisan)->firstOrFail();

return view('html.post')->with('post', $post);

Second firstOrFail or first method will return a model not an array. So you have to print it like this {{ $post->sinopsisPendek }}

If you still have a problem try dump the $post variable before sending it to the view.

Comment: why not `Rilisan::find($id_rilisan)` then? :)

Comment: yeah why not :) but I wanted to show him that there is a method out of the box to check if it is null...